Loss of coherence in the double-slit experiment
Let's suppose we perform the double-slit experiment, using two detectors to detect which slit the particle has passed through. I describe the detectors using quantum mechanics, so they are represented by a state. Thus:
Let the interaction with the slits and detectors be unitary; after the interaction my state is as follows: $|\phi\rangle = a|s_1\rangle |1\rangle |0\rangle + b|s_2\rangle |0\rangle |1\rangle$

$|s_1\rangle$ and $|s_2\rangle$ refers to the passage through the slit
The other two terms in the ket $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$ (and vice versa) indicate which detectors have clicked. $|1\rangle$ represents a detector that has detected a particle, while $|0\rangle$ represents a detector that has not detected anything.
Thus, $|s_1\rangle |1\rangle |0\rangle$ indicates that the particle passed through slit 1 and triggered the first detector but not the second.
Similarly, $|s_2\rangle |0\rangle |1\rangle$ indicates that the particle passed through slit 2 and triggered the second detector but not the first.

Even though the state $|\phi\rangle$ is coherent and maintains quantum superposition, we do not observe the interference pattern when we perform a measurement of the possible paths without directly observing the detectors.
Why is it that, despite the state being coherent, we do not see the interference pattern? Why do we not observe the interference pattern when we trace out the detectors and perform a measurement on the particle's path?

There is a loss of initial coherence from the initial state to the detector interaction state.  I.e. the EM field that directed the particle initially thru the 2 slits was irreversibly changed upon detector interaction.

Just to add to @my2cts correct and concise answer (which I upvoted): This experiment has been performed, see:
Young's double-slit experiment with single photons and quantum eraser
Being orthogonal, they are distinguishable.  If it is possible, even in principle, to distinguish the which slit information, there will be no interference.  And in fact, they can be made orthogonal initially; and then be later mixed back together again, so their earlier path information is now lost.  In that case, interference effects will appear.
Further: you can vary the ability to distinguish the paths between 100% and 0% and any amount in between. There is a corresponding variation in the resulting pattern, i.e. more of an interference pattern or less.  So it need not be all or nothing.

There is no interference because the states $|1\rangle |0\rangle$ and $|0\rangle |1\rangle$ are orthogonal. If they were not, your detector would not detect the which way information.
